# Retrieving thread id's upon execution and completion? Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

How would you go about retrieving the id of a thread when it has been executed and then again when its completed.

Thus printing them in order of their execution/completion from within the main thread.

I am using a forkjoinpool and executing a callable class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add to your task class something like this:

```
executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Running task in" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                <your code>
                System.out.println("Finished task in" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Cheers, but I need to return the id to the main thread for printing there. (I should of specified.)

Comment: In this case you can put this information into blocking queue from tasks and fetch these values and print them in main thread, but if main thread will waits until some data to print arrives, it will be locked.

Answer (score 1):

Create wrapper that implements `Callable` and calls another callable inside. But also retrieves the Thread ID and do with it what you want, e.g.:

```
class ThreadTrackingCallable<V> implements Callable<V> {
    private Callable<V> payload;
    ThreadTrackingCallable(Callable<V> payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
    V call() throws Exception {
       jobStarted(getCurrentThreadId());
       V result = payload.call();
       jobEnded(getCurrentThreadId());
       return result;
    }

    private int getCurrentThreadId() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }
}
```